# UDP over Internet

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp, winsock

I have a small problem: I want to program a simple application that sends a small word (in this case: "Hello") to a server. This Server should display it via `cout`.  This is just a project to learn how network programming works in C++ because I want to create a "small" Internet game. This is also why I use UDP instead of TCP.

The problem is the following: When I start the server on my PC and the Client on my PC and enter 127.0.0.1 as the ip address to send the word to, it works fine, if I enter my local ip it also works fine. But if I enter my public ip, the server does not receive anything.

When I run the Clicnt on my laptop, connected to the same LAN as my PC, and enter the public ip of my router, it also works. When I try it over the Internet (A friend of mine running the Client) the server does not receive anything. I forwarded all Port that I tried to my PC and also disabled Firewall and all Anti-Virus softwares.

I Googled the last 2 days, but i haven't found anything. So maybe someone can help me here?

(Here is my code, if it helps you...)

SERVER:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Benötigter Aufruf vor Socketinitialisierung
    WSAData w;
    if(int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&w) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Sockets konnten nicht initialisiert werden: "<<res << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Socket initialisieren
    cout << "Socket wird initialisiert" << endl;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); //AF_INET = benutze IPv4 SOCK_DGRAM = Verbindungslos, IPPROTO_UDP = Protokoll UDP
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        cout << "Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN sockAdress;
    sockAdress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    cout << "Port:" << endl;
    unsigned short port;
    cin >> port;

    sockAdress.sin_port = htons(port);
    sockAdress.sin_addr.s_addr = ADDR_ANY;

    cout << "Verbindung wird gebunden..." << endl;

    int bindResult = bind(sock,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAdress),sizeof(sockAdress));
    if(bindResult==-1)
    {
        cout << "Konnte Socket nicht binden" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Erfolgreich gebunden!" << endl;

    while(true)
    {
        char buf[256];
        sockaddr_in clientSock;
        int length = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
        int recError = recvfrom(sock,reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf),sizeof(buf),0,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&clientSock),&length);
        if(recError == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Error receving Message" << endl;
        }
        buf[recError] = '\0';
        cout << buf;
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Benötigter Aufruf vor Socketinitialisierung
    WSAData w;
    if(int res = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&w) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Sockets konnten nicht initialisiert werden: "<<res << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Socket initialisieren
    cout << "Socket wird initialisiert" << endl;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); //AF_INET = benutze IPv4, SOCK_DGRAM = Verbindungslos, IPPROTO_UDP = Protokoll UDP
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        cout << "Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN sockAdress;
    sockAdress.sin_family = AF_INET;


    cout << "IP Adresse:" << endl;
    string ip;
    cin >> ip;

    cout << "Port:" << endl;
    unsigned short port;
    cin >> port;
    cout << port << endl;

    sockAdress.sin_port = htons(port);
    sockAdress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());

    cout << "Verbindung wird hergestellt..." << endl;

    string sendText = "Hallo\n";
    cout << sendText.c_str() << endl;
    int sendError = sendto(sock,sendText.c_str(),sendText.length(),0,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAdress), sizeof(sockAdress));
    if(sendError==SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "Konnte nicht senden... " << sendError << endl;
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it works locally, then it's not a problem with the program, the problem is with your router configuration. So it's off-topic here. Try superuser.com.

Comment: What port are you using ? Some ISP's block all ports below a certain range so that would explain why you are not receiving anything. Try for instance 10000.

Comment: I am using port 25565 (minecraft port, because i know it workes with a minecraft server)

Comment: @DMCKITT: The code is fine (though your error handling needs some work). This is a networking problem, not a coding problem. Double-check your router/firewall settings, double-check your friend's router/firewall settings, double-check your ISP's blockage policy, and use a packet sniffer like WireShark to check whether packets are being transmitted and received at each network segment between you and your friend. Chances are, you will find that packets sent from your friend's PC are not reaching your server PC. Either they are getting lost online, or your router is not forwarding them.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine is behind a firewall (it is) then it is not really 'on' the internet. It is on a private network and the router acts as a gateway to the internet. This is by design because:

1. it keeps your computer safe[r]
2. There are not enough internet addresses to give one to each host in the world.

You will need to perform the following steps:

1. determine your router's internet address and use that for the destination of the client program. (for example: http://whatismyipaddress.com)
2. configure your router to forward port `Port` to your server machine's local network address (should begin with 192, 172 or 10). This allows internet hosts to send packets to your server via your gateway.
3. Get a book on TCP/IP networking and read as far as Network Address Translation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i know all this... I already forwarded the port to my local ip. I also informed me about NAT, but it did not helped me...

Comment: @DMCKITT did you forward the port for UDP? routers often select TCP by default.

Comment: Yes I forwarded it for both.